# How to add json data to redirect in Node Js?

Tags: node.js

this route takes information json

```
router.get('/sendOtpforMobileVerification', async (req, res) => {
    console.log("\n//Registration PID 9".bold)
    console.log("\nVOID API (PID 9) : Sending Verification Email".cyan.bold);


    const userIdForOtpVerification = req.body.id;
    const userPhoneForOtpVerification = req.body.mobile;

    ...bla bla bla

});
```

The above URL is working as expected.
what I am trying to do is perform its action from another route

//some other route

```
router.get('/change', async (req, res) => {
res.redirect('/void/api/authentication/sendVerificationMail');
-here i want to call the above route with json data
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can pass query params to the redirect route, which are accessible from the query parameters, as follows:

```
const url = require('url');   

res.redirect(url.format({
       pathname:"/anythingyouwant",
       query: {
          "something":"your infos here"
        }
     }));
```

Then you can get access to the passed query with the following:

```
app.get('/anythingyouwant', function(req, res) {
  var passedVariable = req.query.something;
});
```

Comment: yes i thought of it but the URL which I have to launch will accept only json data

Comment: and i convert the code to query params then I have to change a lot of code

Answer (score 1):

Router functions is independ functions among their. You can create a global value(class, static value etc.) and you send a request from client to server for first get function and thus you store the data and then you can send a new request from client to server, thus you can use the stored data.

Comment: will try that and let u know